# How can I transform Char to Int in Haskell using "ord" function?

Tags: haskell

I have been trying to figure out how can I covert a Char to an Int in Haskell using the "ord" function from the Data.Char library. Here is where I got to now:

```
charToNum :: Char -> Int
charToNum x = (ord(x))
```

It is a pretty simple program, but I'm not a 100% sure how to work with an "ord" function

When I run compile the program, everything compiles, but when I try to enter a character I get this error:

```
> charToNum e
<interactive>:85:11: error: Variable not in scope: e :: Char
```

Comment: What error message do you get / how does your program behave unexpectedly?

Comment: When I try to compile it, it works fine, but after I try to enter a character, I get this error message charToNum e

<interactive>:85:11: error: Variable not in scope: e :: Char

Answer (score 7):

`e` is not a character. I mean, it is of course a character of the string you typed into the prompt, like `c` and `N` are characters of that string, but as far as the parser is concerned all of these represent just parts of variable names. And, well, as GHCi then tells you that there is no variable named `e`.

If you want to pass *the character ‘e’* as an argument then do just that!

```
> charToNum 'e'
```

Answer (score 3):

`charToNum 'e'`?

BTW, your definition should read

```hs
charToNum x = ord x
```

(Or simply

```hs
charToNum = ord
```

)

Comment: Right, or even just omit defining `charToNum` altogether and instead call `ord` directly.

Comment: "Should" is too strong a word to use here. That other definition would be better style, but there is nothing semantically wrong with the definition as written.

Comment: @amalloy true, but I agree with bipll that superfluous parentheses _should_ generally speaking be omitted.